# can optional parameter be put before params of same type in C#

Tags: c#

In other words: Is this possible?

```
public void ShowMessage(string cultureKeyText, string cultureKeyTitle = null, params string[] fields)
```

when using comma separated list to call it. How would it know if 2nd parameter is actually 2nd parameter or 1st in comma separated list of 3rd parameter?

**EDIT: And does overloading really solve it:**

```
 public void ShowError(string cultureKeyText, string cultureKeyCaption);
 public void ShowError(string cultureKeyText, params string[] fields);
 public void ShowError(string cultureKeyText, string cultureKeyCaption, params string[] fields)
```

if I now call
    ShowError("First", "Some");

how does it know if Some is call to 1st or 2nd method?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) does not explicitly cover the `params` case. Did you try compiling that code? What did the compiler say?

Comment: i can't at the moment without installing stuff at home. sorry about being lazy.

Comment: @matti, you can use an online environment such as [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: @matti read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the method you have provided will compile and run properly.  It is valid code.

If you call it with `ShowMessage("1", "2", "3");` then it will interpret `2` as the `cultureKeyTitle` parameter, not the first parameter of the `params` field.

Just like any other optional argument, all *previous* optional arguments must be given a value before you can provide a value for a a given parameter (when not using named parameters).

If you *wanted* to specify that "2" and "3" were two arguments to the `params` field and that `cultureKeyTitle` would use it's optional argument, instead of what would happen using a "normal" call, you would need to use named parameters, like so:

```
ShowMessage("1", fields: new[] { "2", "3" });
```

Comment: ok. what would happen when calling like this: ShowMessage("1", "2);

Comment: @matti The "1" is the first argument, the "2" is the second.  You can't specify the third argument while omitting the second (without named parameters) so that's the only option.  There is no ambiguity.

Comment: ok. thanks. i thought i always have to specify at least one value to params. my bad.

Comment: @matti You do not.  For the simple test of that, make a method with only one `params` parameter.  You can call it without passing any parameters.  It will result in an empty (and not null) array.

Comment: thanks a lot. i do not have environment at home and was too lazy to download one (and yes, read the comment about online environment),

Answer (score 1):

> How would it know if 2nd parameter is actually 2nd parameter or 1st in comma separated list of 3rd parameter

if you call your method like this

```
 ShowMessage("1","2", "3", "4", "5" );
```

then 2 will be taken as `cultureKeyTitle`. But if you want to skip the optional parameter then you will have to do it like this

specify the `parameter name` you are trying to assign to and now the `cultureKeyTitle` will be assigned the default value

```
ShowMessage("", fields: new[] { "", "", "" }); //call
```

Comment: thanks. i was designing to use optional until i understood the problem. i'll use overloading.

Comment: i have given a solution as well, if you don't want to overload

Comment: sure, but it's bad design as u said. forcing to use parameter name in call just to avoid writing an overloaded method is stupid.

Comment: this design will confuse the user, that is why i will not recommend. if you can overload surely do it

Comment: i tried it but it said 3 minutes. But then I understood that does it really solve it. See my edit in question.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question of how the OP's code behaves.

Comment: @Servy OP already knows that this is ambiguity and that is why he asked the question in the first place. And by the way how is your answer different then mine?

Comment: @matti yes you are right overloading won't solve. you have to name the parameters if you want to skip the optional parameter

Comment: @NoOne There is no ambiguity here for the compiler. It's clearly knows what to do.  Some people may have difficulty understanding it, but it's not truly ambiguous.  The rules very clearly state what should be done here.  My answer is different in that it *answers the question*.  The question is how the given method will behave when called.  *You don't answer that question*.  You give an answer of how to make it to something *else* using a non-standard call.  He didn't ask how to do that, he asked what his current code does.  You're assuming skipping the optional is the question; it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically it's valid.

You can invoke this way:

```
ShowMessage(cultureKeyText: "cvbncbn", fields: new[] { "ff", "gh" });
```

Comment: Ok, thats right, I Provided a solution with named parameters, but you made it already as I see. :)